# How to select ToggleButton with the same id on different layout

Tags: android, android-layout, selenium, mobile, ios-ui-automation

I have the following hierarchy:

[image]

Do you have any idea how to interact with the second ToggleButton  - The one that exists under the second LinearLayout(8)?
Please note that the 2 ToggleButtons have the same id/class. The only difference is the text on the buttons.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign a different tag to each ToggleButton so that you can use [findViewWithTag()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#findViewWithTag(java.lang.Object))

to access the buttons separately.

Answer (score 0):

It is best to fetch the enclosing element first:

```
LinearLayout enclosingLayout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.enclosungElement1);
```

Then find the child view also by using findViewById:

```
ToggleButton button = (ToggleButton) enclosingLayout.findViewById(R.id.yourToggleButton);
```

Answer (score 0):

If i follow it correct..

1. You can use SetTag for the views and find later with fiViewByTag(Tag of the view).

   **OR**
2. Just find the parent linear layout like findViewById(LinearLayout(8)).
   and get the chield as parent.findViewById(toggle Button.)